# Xamarin forms: ImageCropper.Forms: How to remove the multiple pop-up?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using [ImageCropper.Forms](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms) for cropping the image selected from the camera and gallery. I have 3 options for changing a profile picture; Take Photo, Upload from Gallery and Select Avatar. So for showing the Media options I am using a `DisplayActionSheet` like below:

```
var actionSheet = await DisplayActionSheet(null,"Cancel", null, "Take Photo", "Upload from Gallery", "Select Avatar");
if (actionSheet == "Take Photo")
{
    OpenCamera();
}
else if(actionSheet == "Upload from Gallery")
{
    Opengallery();
}
else if(actionSheet == "Select Avatar")
{
    OpenAvatar();
}
```

OpenCamera() and Opengallery() are added below. That code is also asking the `Take Photo` and `Photo Library` options again as a popup. I don't need that pop up, is there any way to remove the second popup asked by `ImageCropper.Forms` and load the camera or gallery directly?

**My Code:**

```
    async void OpenCamera()
    {
        try
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
            //I need to open camera only here, no need of a pop up again.
            new ImageCropper()
            {
                PageTitle = "Test Title",
                AspectRatioX = 1,
                AspectRatioY = 1,
                CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
                SelectSourceTitle = "Select source",
                TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",
                PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library",
                Success = (imageFile) =>
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        profilephoto.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                    });
                }
            }.Show(this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CameraException:>" + ex);
        }
    }

async void Opengallery()
{
    try
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        //I need to open gallery only here, no need of a pop up again.
        new ImageCropper()
        {
            PageTitle = "Test Title",
            AspectRatioX = 1,
            AspectRatioY = 1,
            CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
            SelectSourceTitle = "Select source",
            TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",
            PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library",
            Success = (imageFile) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    profilephoto.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                    //var stream = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                    //imagefile = imageFile;
                });
            }
        }.Show(this);
    }
}
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYBuu.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default alert is been defined in the package . So I don't think we can block it directly  . If you want to set the text of it you just need to set

```
SelectSourceTitle = " ",
TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",
PhotoLibraryTitle = "Upload from Gallery"
```

Comment: I have one more issue related to this package, please give a reply for that.

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: I need to save the final picture to server, for that I need the stream & path value of the final image, could you please check the question again? (after screenshot)